# How do I prove if a relations is symmetric,transitive or reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have no idea how to start this problem. It is asking to prove if the following relation R on the set of all integers where $(x,y) \in R$ is reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive.

1) $(x, y)\in R \iff x\neq y$

2) $(x, y)\in R\iff x = y + 1 \;\text{ or }\;  x = y - 1.$

Comment: Do you know what it means to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$(1)$

- (Reflexive?) Can it ever be the case that $x \neq x$? No: no ordered pair of the form $(x, x)$ can be in the relation R.
- (Symmetric?) For all $x, y \in \mathbb Z$, does $x\neq y $ imply $y\neq x$? Of cource it does.
- (Transitive?) Suppose $x \neq y$ and $y\neq z$. Does this necessarily mean that $x\neq z$? Hint: let $x = z = 1, y = 2$. So $(1, 2) \in R$ and $(2, 1) \in R$, but clearly, $(1, 1)\notin R$ because $1 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the second relation, I think it is reflexive and transitive. Am I initially correct?

Comment: The second relation cannot be reflexive because it will never happen that $x = x+1$. So $(x, x)\notin R$. With respect to transitivity, suppose $x = 4, y = 3, z = 2$. Then $4 = 3+1$ so $(x, y)\in R$. And $3 = 2 + 1$. So $(y, z) \in R$. But $4 \neq 2+1$, so $(x, z) \notin R$. Hence, it is **not** the case that $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ imply $(x, z)\in R$. I.e., transitivity fails.

Comment: However, the relation (second relation) is symmetric, as is the first. Can you see why?

Comment: is it because x = y + 1 imply that y = x + 1?

Comment: No, it's symmetric because if we know $(x, y) \in R$, that means, say, $x = y+1 \implies x-1 = y \iff y = x-1$, which satisfies the relation's requirement. Likewise, if $x = y-1 \implies y = x + 1$. Does that make sense? Remember, $(x, y) \in R \iff x = y+1 \text{ OR } x = y-1$.

Comment: Yea I got it. Thanks for the help..!!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- $(1,1)\not\in \mathcal R$ since $1=1$ hence $\mathcal R$ isn't reflexive.
- If $x\ne y$ then $y\ne x$ so...
- $(1,2)\in\mathcal R$ and $(3,1)\in\mathcal R$ but $(1,1)\not\in \mathcal R$ so...

I leave the second relation for you.